# Power BI DAX Flag duplicated value columns in a visual matrix

Tags: powerbi, dax

This is my dashboard :

[image]

```
DATE (year-month)   ORDER           
SLICER              SLICER  

                        
                    
ID  CLIENT  ORDER   AMOUNT  TYPE    TYPE_NUM    NEW_AMOUNT (ABS)
44  ABC     10015   -135    NEG     0           135
44  ABC     10015   -53     NEG     0           53
44  ABC     10015   135     POS     1           135
```

There's a lot of records and columns in my fact table (DATA SALES). I need some of them.
Some orders are paid, (last row on my example) it's a positive **135**.
Some orders don't have this issue, they are perfectly paid.

I have been working with Flagged *calculated columns* , but they don't work on a visual matrix.

I need to get a column that Flags the  **NEW_AMOUNT (ABS)** column and as a result, it should displays if the value on the cell is a duplicated value or not.

Just for the record. Maybe **order 23153** has the same problem but with different amounts.

[image]

DATE (year-month)           ORDER
SLICER                      SLICER

```
ID  CLIENT  ORDER   AMOUNT  TYPE    TYPE_NUM    NEW_AMOUNT (ABS)     FLAG
44  ABC     10015   -135    NEG     0           135                  duplicate
44  ABC     10015   -53     NEG     0           53                   unique
44  ABC     10015   135     POS     1           135                  duplicate
```

Answer (score 1):

Your calculated column has to store the current row's ORDER and NEW_AMOUNT (ABS) values in variables for comparison.
I used the variable DuplicateCheck calculates the number of rows in DATA SALES that have the same ORDER and NEW_AMOUNT (ABS) as the current row.

Then I use an IF statement to check if DuplicateCheck is greater than 1 and mark it as "duplicate". If there's only one occurrence, I mark it as "unique".

```
FLAG = 
VAR CurrentOrder = 'DATA SALES'[ORDER]
VAR CurrentAmount = 'DATA SALES'[NEW_AMOUNT (ABS)]
VAR DuplicateCheck = 
    CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS('DATA SALES'), 
        FILTER(
            'DATA SALES', 
            'DATA SALES'[ORDER] = CurrentOrder && 
            'DATA SALES'[NEW_AMOUNT (ABS)] = CurrentAmount
        )
    )
RETURN
IF(DuplicateCheck > 1, "duplicate", "unique")
```

[image]